# Standard file logger that uses date for file-naming?

Tags: java, logging, java.util.logging

I'm not too familiar with Java logging configuration but I basically would like my app-logging to work in the same way as when using a wrapper config file to run a Java app:

```
wrapper.logfile.rollmode=DATE
wrapper.console.format=PM
wrapper.console.loglevel=INFO
wrapper.logfile=/home/logs/wrapper_YYYYMMDD.log
wrapper.logfile.format=LPTM
wrapper.logfile.loglevel=FINER
wrapper.logfile.maxsize=1m
wrapper.logfile.maxfiles=0
```

This seems quite different from a typical logging.properties file:

```
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = logs/java%u.log
java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit = 100000
java.util.logging.FileHandler.count = 1
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.XMLFormatter
```

Is there an easy way to get the same thing? I'm a bit confused how the wrapper maps to configuring loggers internally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asking about comparing the default Java Logger to the [Tanuki Service Wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp), you are comparing apples to oranges. The Tanuki service wrapper actually implements it's own logging system... in C ([header file for the logging code](http://sourceforge.net/p/wrapper/code/1764/tree/trunk/wrapper/src/c/logger.h)). So it really has nothing to do with Java logging.

Unfortunately, the default logging system in Java (the `java.util.logging` package) does not support daily log rotation. [There's a bug open](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6350749) to add this functionality, but it is currently unresolved. The bug report mentions that its possible to write a custom handler to do this, but that seems like a lot of work and the bug report mentions that it may interfere with other applications.

By far the simplest solution would be to use [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch), which is the successor for [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/), another viable alternative. Either of these third-party, open-source libraries provide a daily rolling file appender option out of the box.

For example, from the [documentation](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html), here is an example of a `logback.xml` file that configures Logback to log to a file that is rolled-over daily with each file being up to 1 MB in size:

```
<configuration>
  <appender name="ROLLING" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>mylog.txt</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <!-- rollover daily -->
      <fileNamePattern>mylog-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.txt</fileNamePattern>
      <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
        <!-- or whenever the file size reaches 1MB -->
        <maxFileSize>1MB</maxFileSize>
      </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>


  <root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="ROLLING" />
  </root>

</configuration>
```